# How to replace login with logout after user logged in?

Tags: php, html

```
<div id="nav">  
<div id="nav_wrapper"><br/>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="login.html">ログイン</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my nagivation bar where the login button is located

```
<?php
session_start();

include "connection.php";

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pass']);

$sql = "Select * from user where username = '".$username.
"' and password = '".md5($password)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0)
{
    $sql = "Select * from user where username = '".$username.
    "' and password = '".$password."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong username / password! Please try again!');";
        die("window.history.go(-1);</script>");
    }
}

if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
}

if($_SESSION['role']==="1")
{
    echo "<script>alert('Welcome back! ".$_SESSION['username']."');";
    echo "window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
}
else if($_SESSION['role']==="0")
{
    echo "<script>alert('Welcome back, Admin!');";
    echo "window.location.href='admin.html';</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
}
?>
```

And this is my login.html, may I know how to replace login with logout after user has logged in?
I have seen some questions before but I just cant understand it.
Sorry for stupid question as I am still new to html

Comment: do you realize how unsafe **this entire script is?** is this for academic purposes or are you intending on going live?

Comment: I guess you don't care about security then. You're going to eventually get hacked and come running back here after, I'm betting on it.

Comment: Yes bro, this is for my assignment purpose

Comment: Is your assignment to make a application that exposes as many security exploits as possible?

Comment: @HåkenLid This is what my lecturer taught me on class, I dont really know this is unsecure

Comment: Read the articles linked from one of the answers. And research "SQL injection".

Comment: *"This is what my lecturer taught me on class"* - I think you need to find yourself a new lecturer who knows about 21st century database/password storage methods and who doesn't still live in the 90's where all these vulnerabilities have since been replaced by something safe. This lecturer probably still thinks that MD5 is safe and also doesn't know about what a prepared statement is, and storing vital information in sessions. If you paid this person for this, you should get your money back, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply compare the `SESSION` value to determine if thee user is logged in or not.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo '<li><a href="login.html">ログイン</a></li>';
}else
{
    echo '<li><a href="logout.html">Logout</a></li>';
}
```

And try to not use `md5` for encrypting passwords. Use [PHP's own password hashing algos](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. Also use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), because escaping string is not that secure either.

Also don't store password and other sensitive information in the sessions, they can be easily hijacked.

Comment: you left an important detail out. Can you spot what else they're doing that is so unsafe that I shiver at the thought of.

Comment: If you look at Tricia's answer, you'll see she just made a quick edit about it ;-)

Comment: Put it where you are using the navigation. And also remember to `start_session()` in that page. And be sure to follow the security advice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are going to destroy the sessions when they log out - something like this should work...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      echo //logout button here
  } else {
      echo //log in button here
  }
```

also md5 is not very secure - and why are you posting the password to a session variable?